# How to validate legitimacy of nodes in a public P2P network (peer.js)

Tags: authentication, webrtc, p2p, hmac, peerjs

<s>I have</s> There is a public P2P network and nodes (based on peer.js) which has following conditions:

- Anyone (includes malicious nodes) can join to the P2P network
- Every legitimate nodes have one common security key that shared via secure way

Under the conditions, The nodes have to establish full-mesh connection between only legitimate nodes.

Here, I need to implement a secure negotiation protocol which will be used before establishing a connection between nodes. I need to ensure that every node should shut malicious nodes out through the negotiation, maybe, with the common security key which shared only among legitimate nodes.

I think there would be a well-known solution for this situation, but I couldn't find it yet. What is a typical solution to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a peer to peer network requires a signalling server of some sort. Simply let this server authenticate peers. You mention a key, use this key to authenticate a peer and only allow an authenticated peer to join the network.
Usually you see clients connecting to rooms directly, but you can wait for them to authenticate before allowing them to create or join a room. You can achieve this by simply not sending a client's data through to other clients when not authenticated yet, or by making the room id secret and only giving out the secret id to authenticated clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't let the signaling server authenticate peers because I don't own the signaling server. it's out of my control.

Comment: @KoheiNozaki Well, use one that is in your control then... Or use a separate portal to authenticate and somehow make connecting to this signalling server only possible after authenticating (by fetching the server's ip/url from this auth portal for example). But keep in mind that this will never be as secure.

Comment: Unfortunately again, using one under my control is not an option in my case... the point of this question is that how can I use the one which is out of my control securely.

Comment: @KoheiNozaki Well, you could let existing peers authenticate new peers and boot them out if they fail to authenticate, but then they are already in your "secured" network. If you want only legitimate peers in your network you need a way to authenticate them before connecting, period.

Comment: I can't ensure that there are only legitimate peers in the P2P network because it's a public, insecure one as I mentioned in the question...

Comment: What I need is a way to distinguish if a node is legitimate or malicious, in a conversation between two nodes.